# Android Pending Intent with Alarm Manager not working

Tags: android

Not sure what is the issue here. The following code does not work. I have used pending intent before using similar code but never faced this issue. Kindly help.

The log statements from Main.java are getting printed but nothing gets logged from PublicData.class

Main.java

```
AlarmManager alarm;
long gap = 1800000;
Calendar cal;

Log.d("Stoned", "pending intent about to create");
Intent i = new Intent(this, PublicData.class);
PendingIntent pint = PendingIntent.getService(
        this, 0, i, 0);
Log.d("Stoned", "pending intent creating");
alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
        gap, pint);
Log.d("Stoned", "pending intent created");
```

PublicData.java

```
public class PublicData extends IntentService {


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Log.d("Stoned", "In pending intent");

    }

.
.
```

Comment: Follow these steps 1. extends BroadcastReceiver 2. use onReceive() Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112247/could-alarmmanager-setinexactrepeating-not-broadcast-intents-when-the-device-is/20112991#20112991)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second parameter is the offset, when the alarm will be called for the first time. If you use the current time this will take thousands of hours to first call...

`alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), gap, pint);`

Should be (for immediate repeating)

`alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0, gap, pint);`

See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

---

EDIT:

You can also use this:

```
long interval = DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS * 30;
long firstWake = System.currentTimeMillis() + interval;
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstWake, interval, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is facing the same problem, the following thing worked for me. I added 'android:exported="true"' in the service declaration in the manifest. Also, I used the entire packagename instead of just the classname for the service. It worked after making these changes.

```
<service android:name="com.abc.def.PublicData" android:exported="true" >
```